# Use Vue attr inside render_field widget_tweaks django

Tags: django, vue.js, django-widget-tweaks

**file.html**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{%render_field set_pass_form.password v-on:blur="passwordOnBlur()" %}
```

**Gives error:**

```
'render_field' tag requires a form field followed by a list of attributes and values in the form attr="value"
```

But when I use v-on:blur in normal  tag it works without error:

```
<input type="email" name="email"   v-on:blur="passwordOnBlur()" >
```

How to use `v-on:blur=""` in `{% render_field %}` tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[see example in the document](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks)

```
<!-- double colon -->
{% render_field form.search_query v-bind::class="{active:isActive}" %}
```